# Requesting API leads to success on browser but status code 500 in node-red

Tags: node.js, glassfish, node-red

I'm trying to call an API with "http request" node in node-red (node.js).
After setting an enviroment variable `"HTTP_PROXY=http://******"`, I could call Web pages (such as "http: //google.com") with a response of `status code 200`, but failed to call the API with `status code 500` in node-red. 
**I could call the API by entering URL directly on browser** (Internet Explorer).
How can I solve the problem and call the API in node-red(node.js)? (what's the difference between the two means (node-red and browser))?

Comment: The API URL is "http://〜〜〜".

Comment: Status 500 means there was an error on the server side -- so it seems like your http request made it to the server, but something you sent caused an exception while processing the request. You'll probably need to debug the server logs.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I could make a little progress, but still 500.

Comment: I found out that I could reach the root directory of web server, or the part of API URL  that didn't include any parameters (The page displayed "your server is now running"). However, when I appended the path and parameters to the root URL, it responded status code 500 again....

Comment: Sounds like the API url is being mal-formed, either by your node-red flow or some bad msg data. Can you update the post to show `http request` node properties, and debug output of the `msg` object being passed to it?

Comment: I made it! I had the administrator of the API to check the server log.The reason of code 500 was an insufficient `msg.headers` to call the API. `msg.headers["Accept-Encoding"]` was not set in node-red by default (browser did ), so `msg.headers["Accept-Encoding"]="***"` solved my problem. Without your first advice, I wouldn't have done it. So, please answer this question formally and I will accept that and close here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have verified that the API is expecting certain headers, and throws an exception without them (ouch, bad practice!).

Anyway, to invoke the API with additional headers, you can use a `change` node to add them to the msg object, right before invoking the `http request` node:

[image]